# D3.js Zoomable Treemap library version incompatibility with other charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been trying to integrate a Bubble chart, a word cloud and a zoomable treemap from the [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) library in a single html page. Problem is that the first two charts work with the d3.v3.min.js(v3.3.11)  library whereas the Zoomable treemap refers to the d3.js library (v2.4.4). So the cross referencing of the two versions results in the bubble and treemap charts not being rendered.Also they both are not able to work on either mentioned verions.Please help.

Is there a way to isolate the referencing of the library files to specific pages in my app.

Comment: In general, you can't have different versions of the same library on the same page. But [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/nCYW8_F3AnM/8mYOQBfd0QsJ) might help re zoomable treemap.

Answer (score 0):

Zoomable treemap example is referencing an older version of D3, fortunately this functionality is included in the newer version.

You must only include one instance of D3 to run things on your page. In this case use d3.v3.min.js

Comment: I have already tried rendering a zoomable treemap with d3.v3.min.js... not working.

Comment: ok can you post a bit more details? browser version, javascript console log (or an js error if you are getting any)